# Algorithm for slicing vector evenly

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Let's say I'm reading in a file of size: 11520000+ etc.. I need to process this file. Obviously, processing the entire file on it's own is going to be memory intensive and not very practical. The file sizes however change but all seem to be very large.

I'm just wondering if there is a generic algorithm for dividing the vector into evenly sized blocks?

For example:

If the block size was 8, then we could divide the block into 4 segments each segment containing 2 values:

```
0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0
```

Would then result in:

```
Seg1:
0 1 
Seg2:
1 0 
Seg3
0 1
Seg4
1 0
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

The file is a .wav file, containing double values.

Comment: Do you mean something a lot different from `block_size = total_size / num_blocks;`?

Comment: Is the file binary or text? Or, more importantly, is the file composed of records, each the same size, or variable sized records (i.e. line).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hey yes, kind of. I just want to be able to process the file in smaller chunks, rather than the entire file whole. Without missing any of the important data inside the file.. How would you therefore determine the `num_blocks`?

Comment: What is the structure of the data in the file?

Comment: @Arkadiy The file is a .wav file containing (double) values, therefore, it would need to be split evenly

Comment: Nothing but doubles? No header or other metadata?

Comment: @Arkadiy No header data, just double values.. I've already stored the header and metadata somewhere else.. This just contains the raw samples :)

Comment: "How would you therefore determine the num_blocks?" - check how much RAM you have and work backwards from there. Or just pick some fairly large `block_size`.

Comment: Do you know what "prime factorization" is? You would have to apply that to the size of your file.

Comment: @Dukeling But then would they be even?

Comment: @user1326876: In that case, you'd probably do the reverse: pick a block size you're comfortable processing (e.g., a few megabytes) then just read a block, process, and repeat until done.

Comment: It rather depends on what kind of processing you're doing. If you just need to "process" individual items, you can read the file sequentially into a concurrent queue, and have multiple threads just pulling items from the queue. If the processing of one item depends on previous values, then you have to think more about splitting it up.

Comment: It may be worth looking at [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) to see if it is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: If you have some block size based on RAM or just some large number, the last block may be smaller (is that the worst thing in the world?), you can reduce the amount with some simple maths, but to eliminate it is a bit more work - think factorization.

Comment: And in fact, eliminating that odd block at the end might not be possible at all. For example, if the size is 1,000,003 bytes (a prime number), then you have two choices for block size: 1 or 1,000,003, unless you allow the odd-sized final block.

Answer (score 1):

1. determine raw data size and format

   - as you wrote you already know the format is stereo doubles (binary)
   - size can be obtained by seek to an end of RAW data file
   - on 32 bit OS beware the 2GB boundary
2. read buffer size depends on what you want to do with the data

   - I assume non-real-time playback
   - use of some filters (like noise reduction, pause removal ...)
   - so you most likely need some previous and in some cases even next samples
   - for large files I use buffer size from 8KB up to 16MB
   - on MCU platforms the sizes usually goes from 32B up to 2KB
   - you have to try few sizes from above intervals (use #define or const)
   - and choose the best compromise between speed and memory consumption
   - most processing algorithms performance saturate on some size value and do not increase with size afterwards
3. read loop

   - the best way for me is that reading the RAW data file is done from main thread (single thread only)
   - and the data is feeded to the processing threads evenly
   - number of threads is usually the number of CPUs
   - do not forget about sharing locks
   - and all threads should have their own buffers

Now the read algorithm:

1. allocate/start threads buffers ...
2. file seek to 0 from start

   - set main index variable, int ix=0;
3. find first thread with empty buffer
4. lock thread/buffer for main thread

   - set its actual index to main ix
   - increment main ix, ix++;
5. copy last samples to buffer if needed for processing
6. if there are none yet copy safe sample values instead (0 for example)
7. read rest of the buffer from RAW file
8. copy safe values if end of file to fill buffer...
9. unlock thread/buffer from main thread
10. if not end of file goto 3

Ok what about the processed data:

- if you have it in memory only then its not a big deal
- if you store it to file again then you need to write also write algorithm
- 1 loop ix from 0 to ...
- 2 wait for thread with the same ix to be done
- 3 lock it for write
- 4 write output data to file
- 5 set thread as empty (ready for new data)
- 6 unlock it.
- PS At the last write you can cut off unused data to match original file size

PS.

- the read can be also done by dividing the entire file to N blocks where N is the number of threads but that requires some processing for merging output data and read is conflicting it self so it is slower ...
- also you can wait for all processing threads to be done and write them all at once (sometimes it is faster sometimes slower ... depends on the processing)

Sorry for code absence but it is all platform/enviroment dependent and you did not specify any so I hope this helps anyway...